# MobileFirst: adapter returned data containing special characters

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webview, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

One of my adapter returns some data containing **special characters (like quotation marks, bullets or question marks etc.)**

[image]

`onSuccess` of adapter call,  I save data in a variable as shown below.

```
try{

   var data = JSON.stringify(response.invocationResult) ;
   var  _meetingDetailsArray = JSON.parse(data).MXEMEETINGSet.EMEETING ;

}catch(Exception) {
    logger.error( Exception );
}
```

After that I pick out the required fields/values and save them in another js object as shown below.

```
    var _summary = ( _meetingDetailsArray.EMEETINGITEM.TCMEETING.VLSUMMARY || "" )  + ( _meetingDetailsArray.EMEETINGITEM.TCMEETING.VLSUMMARY_LONGDESCRIPTION || "" );

//below did not work even
    //_summary = _summary.replace(/\“/g,"&#8220;").replace(/\”/g,"&#8221;").replace(/•/g,"<br>&#8226;");

UserProfile.getUserProfileDetails().userMeetingFullDetails.MeetingItems.STANDARD.Summary.push( _summary  );
```

When viewing results on `devices (iOS, Android)`, it shows strange characters.

[image]

I am using **JQuery Mobile 2.1.3** along with **Bootstrap 3.3.2** and all pages are dynamically loaded. The main `index.html` already contains `chartset` but still no benefit.

```
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

However, on desktop browser like chrome it shows fine.

**Update**

I have applied **iFix v6.3.0.0 InterimFix 201505212300** but still same results

After the update, adapter sends back the special characters as it is, while previously they were converted into Unicode format.

[image]

**Environment:**

- Eclipse -Luna Service Release 2 (**4.4.2**)
- MobileFirst Studio -**6.3.0.00-20150521-2300**
- MobileFirst 6.3 (Build number: **IMF 00-20150521-2300**)
- IBM WAS **Liberty Profile 8.5.5.5 (Base version)**

[image]

**Update 2**

If I run the **common app** through Eclipse development studio on desktop Chrome (`latest Version 43.0.2357.81 m`) and access the backend data through adapters via VPN , then it `shows correct data with correct special characters like quotation marks (") or bullets etc.`

But if I access the same **common app** that is deployed on another server machine (the above specs) in the **same** chrome desktop browser then `it does not handle special characters and shows strange characters.` as show above.

I checked **HTTP request/response** and both are same.

Local development response:

```
GET /myProject/apps/services/preview/eMeeting/common/1.0/default/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.151.59.2:10080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: NID=67=BUovympli30FPUZ9xJ0N8heI22xH4wL8uuy3YPL3n7EmTtSpQ7nQ_VJS0zgGnWbXVmrHAfU1CIER3HhPvGDfkBODxOoKQsXpuCE6punpkrw-WhRZmg7duiZntwqzgjHh; PREF=ID=55ee18705b919343:U=3649ea9bd9b0a9cc:FF=0:TM=1432904549:LM=1432904571:S=7VeFNsfwhAARESRp
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Data: CIa2yQEIpLbJAQiptskBCMS2yQEI6YjKAQj9lcoB

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 3833
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 13:41:45 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Pragma: no-cache
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
```

Response from Server running on another machine:

```
GET /myProject/apps/services/preview/eMeeting/common/1.0/default/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.150.20.51:9080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: NID=67=BUovympli30FPUZ9xJ0N8heI22xH4wL8uuy3YPL3n7EmTtSpQ7nQ_VJS0zgGnWbXVmrHAfU1CIER3HhPvGDfkBODxOoKQsXpuCE6punpkrw-WhRZmg7duiZntwqzgjHh; PREF=ID=55ee18705b919343:U=3649ea9bd9b0a9cc:FF=0:TM=1432904549:LM=1432904571:S=7VeFNsfwhAARESRp
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Data: CIa2yQEIpLbJAQiptskBCMS2yQEI6YjKAQj9lcoB

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 3833
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 13:43:11 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Pragma: no-cache
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
```

Comment: You keep forgetting to mention your MFP version... Try to recrate this with a simple app and not yours, see if it happens (with the response from the server). If it still happens, try to update the studio version as there was recently a fix for special characters in adapters.

Comment: General note: you should not use MFP 6.3 with Liberty 8.5.5.0 - it might work for you, but it's not supported. Upgrade at minimum to 8.5.5.3

Comment: Oh thanks for it, I have missed this info.

Comment: I have updated Eclipse Studio to latest MFP v7.0.0.00-20150430-1556, will it work on MFP v6.3 Server ? I am not sure..... Or I have to update MFP Servers as well to latest version.

Comment: Should work but better to also be in sync with the server and client.

Comment: Studio gives error, like not able to migrate to v7 from 6. Now I am reverting back to 6.3 because on three client machines I have to upgrade servers and it will take time. Can you please tell me which 6.3 intern fix I apply for adapter issue: Here I can see only v6.3 or v7 zips: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_6.3.0.0.zip

Comment: What do you mean. Go to IBM Fix Central and download the latest 6.3

Comment: Okay let me check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue and the problem was the Liberty profile configuration on my Windows 2012 server.
The data returned by the SQL adapter was presented in the phone as gibberish (wrong characters). The data wasn't native english of course.

I assume your production server is indeed **Liberty profile v8.5+**. Try to add following lines in the **jvm.options** file that resides in the same folder/place where **server.xml** exists?

[image]

Remember all lines start with `-D` no spaces before or after:

```
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

[image]

save the file and **restart** the Liberty profile server.

One of them did the trick for me, I guess it is the language one although my  SQL data is not in English.

I suspect the combination of the DB encoding (MySQL 5.6 on Windows) and the Liberty profile default encoding on Windows.

Comment: good it worked for you too. AAhad, did you find which of the 3 flags did the trick?

Answer (score 0):

A recent iFix release for MFPF 6.3 provided the following specific fix: PI39922 UNICODE PARAMETERS ARE ENCODED INCORRECTLY UPON BEING PASSED TO A MOBILEFIRST ADAPTER.

Before the fix, adapter responses could have contained characters such as the ones seen in the image in the question.

And so my first thought is that you need to download the latest available iFix from IBM Fix Central Studio, and test again.

Comment: Thanks, I am downloading it and will update accordingly.

Comment: I found two iFix on iFix Central portal and have applied above one - the latest fix available on portal.

Comment: Can you please see the updated question and suggest ?